# WordPress gallery grid show original image

Tags: wordpress, crop, image-gallery

I'm using the Divi theme to build a website in WordPress. The problem I'm facing is this:

[wrong image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRukP.jpg)

I'm using the gallery module to display a set of pictures in grid mode. But all the images loaded are shown as above. Id like to display the original image instead of the medium one.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivuMu.jpg)

WordPress creates some versions of my images but the aspect ratio is different, so this crop effect is applied on my gallery items.

I have tried to set the correct size on medium images from media settings and generated the images again but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divi theme uses its own functions to generate thumbnails that hard crop original images by default.
Try editing post_thubnails_divi.php file on theme folder using the dimensions that suit you and set the crop value to false.

```
$crop = apply_filters( 'et_post_thumbnails_crop', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can download the Gallery layout and install it in your DIVI theme. it give some layout options for gallery design.
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/free-divi-photo-gallery-layout-pack-5-stunning-gallery-page-layouts-in-one-convenient-download
Note : subscribe it and they will send the downloadable link to your email
thanks